# Is it possible to resize an instance of a class inheriting pygame Surface?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, pygame, pygame-surface

I am trying to make GUI elements using pygame (I know it's odd, but they are to be used inside a pygame made game). Here is a very simplified piece of code of how a UI element class looks like in my code:

```py
import pygame
from typing import Tuple


class UIElement(pygame.Surface):

    def __init__(self, size: Tuple[int, int]) -> None:
        super().__init__(size)

        self.children = {}

    def draw(self) -> None:
        ...
```

Note that the class is just an extension of the `pygame.Surface` class. Now, what I would like to do is make those elements resizable, for example if the size is not prior knowledge, implementing a method with this signature:

```py
def resize(self, size: Tuple[int, int]) -> None:
    ...
```

However, pygame doesn't allow for Surface objects to be resized in-place, which forces me to create a new `UIElement` instance with the right size. I would like this new instance to be a copy of my first instance, except for the size of the `pygame.Surface`, and this new instance should replace the first one. How would I do it from within the first instance with my `resize` method?

I looked through the `copy` module, but it doesn't seem to fit my issue.

Furthermore, I know it may seem simpler to just add a `surface` attribute to my class, which would be holding the `pygame.Surface` object, and set a new value for this attribute when needed but this would force me to go through tremendous architecture redesign work and I would prefer to avoid it.

If you have any idea as how to fix my issue, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't. I suggest using the simple approach. `UIElement` should not be a subclass of `pygame.Surface`. The `pygame.Surface` object should only be an attribute of the `UIElement`. All your problems are caused by inheritance.

A [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object cannot be resized. A *Surface* is just a proxy object for an internally managed, SDL surface object with immutable size. PyGame has no API to change the object under the hood. All you can do is to create a new *Surface* with a different size and use [`pygame.transform.scale()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.scale) to set the content of the scaled *Surface*:

```py
class UIElement(pygame.Surface):
    # [...]

    def resize(self, size):
        scaled_element = UIElement(size)
        pygame.transform.scale(self, size, scaled_element) 
        scaled_element.children = self.children
        return scaled_element
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I know I can drop inheritance but I was asking for a different approach. I asked if it's possible to reinitialize the instance or reinstantiate the class within the instance so that the new instance, which should be in place of the former instance, was initialized with the desired size, and all other attributes are kept the the same.